# Avoiding a large amount of if-else statements in java

Tags: java, if-statement

So I am doing a practice test, and this is the question:

Write a Java method that takes one double value pay as argument and prints
to the standard output the tax rate corresponding to the value of pay entered.
Use the table below to determine the tax rate. (6 points)

If pay more than 100,000, tax rate is 40%

If pay more than 60,000 and less than or equal to 100,000, tax rate is 30%

If pay more than 30,000 and less than or equal to 60,000, tax rate is 20%

If pay more than 15,000 and less than or equal to 30,000, tax rate is 10%

If pay more than 5,000 and less than or equal to 15,000, tax rate is 5%

If pay is less than or equal to 5,000, tax rate is 0

This is the code I Wrote, which works:

```
public class Two {

public static void main(String[] args){
    double j= Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    Two.taxrate(j);}

public static void taxrate(double pay)
{
    if (pay> 100000) {System.out.println(pay*.4);}
    else if (pay>60000) {System.out.println(pay*.3);}
    else if (pay>30000) {System.out.println(pay*.2);}
    else if (pay>15000) {System.out.println (pay*.1);}
    else if (pay>5000) {System.out.println(pay*.05);}
    else System.out.println(0.0);
}}
```

What I want to know is this: is this the best way to answer this question? We have learned how to design data types, and this question seems easy. I feel I'm overlooking something.

Comment: I don't think you can use "switch" here.. Switch is only for specific cases. So, yes, this is "as-of-now" the best practice for your code

Comment: Guava and/or Apache Commons have sorted map containers which allow matching range between keys. Looks like a use case for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As EJP suggested, you want a "table" of salary to tax rate. In a full scale application, this information will likely be stored in a database rather than in memory, but going for something in-between statically defined and a full scale database would be to use a `Map`. Specifically, using a `NavigableMap` will allow very simple access to such calculations:

```
NavigableMap<Double, Double> payToTaxRate = new TreeMap<Double, Double>();

// e.g., loaded from a file:
payToTaxRate.put(100000, 0.4);
payToTaxRate.put(60000, 0.3);
payToTaxRate.put(30000, 0.2);
payToTaxRate.put(15000, 0.1);
payToTaxRate.put(5000, 0.05);
payToTaxRate.put(Double.MIN_VALUE, 0);

System.out.prinln(pay * payToTaxRate.floorEntry(pay).getValue());
```

Naturally, this is overkill for an assignment and the `if` statements would likely be faster than the overhead of the map. However, in a world where tax brackets are literally added from year-to-year (not so often, thankfully), a more dynamic approach like the above is helpful.

Comment: this is a better design tahn what she did.. But is this as efficient as aa group of if-else statements?

Comment: No, it's certainly going to be slower (although not to humans, even if you reinstantiated the `Map` every time). The series of `if` statements are going to beat any data structure that does what the `if` statements do, but you also cannot change the number of them without changing code; you could change, add or remove items from the map on the fly (adding potential concerns, such as thread safety). Any added complexity has trade offs.

Comment: Like I said.. Its a better design, perhaps the best.. Yes, i agree with additional complexity/flexibility, comes additional delay. :)

Comment: this was incredibly helpful

Answer (score 3):

Use a table that gives you lower and/or upper bound and multiplier. Then just scan the table until you find the appropriate row and use that multiplier.

In a real application the table would be in a database, as the powers that be can change the ranges, number of ranges, and multipliers any time.

Comment: And by table, he likely means a [`TreeMap<Double, Double>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Using a TreeMap, you could easily make use of `floorEntry` to get an `Entry` that contains the salary (key) matched with its tax rate (value).

Answer (score 1):

You could always go about it something like this.
It avoids the massive if block, and also adds nicer structure.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Two {

    private static Map<Double, Double> rates = new HashMap<Double, Double>();
    static {
        rates.put(100000d, 0.4d);
        rates.put(60000d, 0.3d);
        rates.put(30000d, 0.2d);
        rates.put(15000d, 0.1d);
        rates.put(5000d, 0.05d);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double j = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        System.out.println(rate(j));
    }

    private static double rate(double pay) {
        for(Double d: rates.keySet())
            if(pay > d) return pay * rates.get(d);
        return 0.0d;
    }

}
```

Comment: wat if pay value is 10001d

Comment: Is 100,001 greater than 100,000? It will return 0.4d.